# Send POST array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, post

When I click submit I need to save the data of each `.product-insert` (so product_name and product_price) in an array like:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        'name'  => 'Camera',
        'price' => 120
    ),
    [1] => array(
        'name'  => 'Radio',
        'price' => 80
    )
);
```

Because I have combined data (product name and price) it is very difficult to loop it.

**My fields:**

```
<div class="product-insert">
    <select name="product_name[]">
      <option value="Camera">Camera</option>
      <option value="Radio">Radio</option>
      <option value="Television">Television</option>
    </select>
   <input name="product_price[]" />
</div><!--End .product-insert-->

<div class="product-insert">
    <select name="product_name[]">
      <option value="Camera">Camera</option>
      <option value="Radio">Radio</option>
      <option value="Television">Television</option>
    </select>
    <input name="product_price[]" />
</div><!--End .product-insert-->

<!--This button can add extra fields with javascript--> 
<input type="button" name="add_product" />

<!--This is the submit button for saving all the fields-->
<input type="submit" name="submit_products" />
```

**This is what I have now:**

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit_products'] ) ) {
    $products = array_combine( $_POST['product_name'], $_POST['product_price'] );
    $products = array_filter( $products );
    $products = array_map( 'htmlentities', $products );
}
```

**Which give the following output:**

```
[Camera] => 120 [Radio] => 80
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Maybe you need another way of doing it>?

Comment: use arrey_keys and loop.

Comment: @bish My question is what I need to change about my current code to realize the first array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows:

```
$product_prices = $_POST['product_price'];
        foreach( $_POST['product_name'] as $key => $value ) {
            $products[] = array( 
                'name'  => $value,
                'price'     => $product_prices[$key]
        ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set names of inputs like so

```
<div class="product-insert">
    <select name="product[0][name]">
      <option value="Camera">Camera</option>
      <option value="Radio">Radio</option>
      <option value="Television">Television</option>
    </select>
   <input name="product[0][price]" />
</div><!--End .product-insert-->
```

If you have another one of this you have change 0 to 1.

Then $_POST will looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Radio
                    [price] => value
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Yes I thought about it. But I do not know if this is a proper way.

Comment: It's definitely better than filtering post array and way more elegant.